# Desktop Notification for Nodewebkit application

Tags: node.js, notifications, desktop-application, skype, node-webkit

I am currently building a `Node webkit` desktop application with Chat implemented it it.
If there any new messages from a user, It should notify similar to Skype above window dock and on click of it it should open application.
I went through a few desktop notification libraries provided:
[Growl](https://github.com/tj/node-growl)
[Node Webkit Desktop Notification](https://github.com/edjafarov/node-webkit-desktop-notification)

Second one worked for me, but it is not interactive.
Are there any other libraries which provide a desktop notification with Skype like behaviour and which works with NodeWebKit?
Or Is there anything which can be changed in `NW Desktop Notification` to make it interactive?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can try electron-tray notifications: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no plugin about it. But I think it can be achieve with creating new window(looks like a popup) while running main window and it can be triggered by socket.io like real time communication engine when new data or new notification comes for user. It looks like push notification.

Answer (score 1):

**Node-Notifier**

A Node.js module for sending cross platform system notifications. Using Notification Center for Mac, notify-osd/libnotify-bin for Linux, Toasters for Windows 8/10, or taskbar Balloons for earlier Windows versions. If none of these requirements are met, Growl is used.

```
$ npm install --save node-notifier


const notifier = require('node-notifier');
notifier.notify('Message');

notifier.notify({
  'title': 'My notification',
  'message': 'Hello, there!'
});
```